# Problem with sed

Tags: sed

```
root@ROUTER:~# cat maccheck.txt 
logread | egrep ': STA |DHCPACK' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$9}' | sed -e 's/\( [0-9] \)/0\1/' | sed "s/.\{15\}/&:/; s/: /:/g" | cut -d : -f 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 | sed "s/.\{13\}/&X/;" | sed 's/:X/ /g' | sed 's/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/AAAA/g' | sort -u -r
```

it OK when it's here:

```
root@ROUTER:~# logread | egrep ': STA |DHCPACK' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$9}' | head -1
Sep 2 03:03:25 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

but it's bad if I use the script that has further things in it:

```
root@ROUTER:~# sh maccheck.txt |head -1
Sep0 4 13:13 AAAA
```

so the "Sep0" is bad.. how to modify it to be "Sep"?

```
root@ROUTER:~# logread | egrep ': STA |DHCPACK' | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$9}' | sed -e 's/\( [0-9] \)/0\1/' | head -1
Sep0 2 03:03:25 AAAA
```

So the problem is with:

```
sed -e 's/\( [0-9] \)/0\1/'
```

**Q:** I need the same output, but without the "0" in "Sep", how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\1` will give you everything listed in your group (the `\( \)` section).  Your group includes the spaces, so the zero will be put in, then the " 2 " will be added.

To fix, change to

```
sed -e 's/ \([0-9]\) / 0\1 /'
```

#### Example

*before*

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed -e 's/\( [0-9] \)/0\1/' 
Sep0 2 03:03:25 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

*after*

```
$ cat sample.txt | sed -e 's/ \([0-9]\) / 0\1 /'
Sep 02 03:03:25 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```